# Phonegap: Check if hardware acceleration is enabled?

Tags: android, css, cordova, css-animations

I develop a simple phonegap game and use some CSS transformations in order to make buttons and ui elements zoom in and fade in:

```
.menuAnim1 {   
    -webkit-animation:  zoomIn 1s;
    -moz-animation:  zoomIn 1s;
    -ms-animation:  zoomIn 1s;
    animation:  zoomIn 1s;
}
```

This works good on phones with Adroid 4.3 and higher. I think because the phones use hardware acceleration.
I got reports from some testers that the performance of these animations on their phones with Android 4.2 (and older) is really bad. I assume because the lack of hardware acceleration?

Is there a way to check if the phone and OS version is able to do hardware acceleration so i can switch the CSS file according to this information?

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/force-hardware-acceleration-with-translate3d-sometimes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware hardware acceleration is enabled by default in versions >= 3.0 - And as such, you shouldn't be seeing such a performance hit by going down a single os version. Of course it all comes down to the hardware at the end of the day.

I can't say I've ever used, or have any knowledge of Phonegap, but in Java, you can test for hardware acceleration with the following:

```
View.isHardwareAccelerated()
```

and

```
Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()
```

Both will return true if so.

**Update** Yup, HA is enabled in 3.0 (API 11) by default. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Comment: Thx. Do you have any information if the browsers on android use HA?